# Consuming Web Services in Lotus Notes shows error message no implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.logfactory

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-notes, axis, apache-commons-logging

I have been struggling this for weeks now.
I tried almost everything.

1. Loosening security
2. Putting earlier version commons-loggings.jar
3. Putting commons-loggins properties file

But all effort in vain. I am not able to run the agent successfully.

The error message is persistent -

`org.apache.commons.discovery.discoveryexception no implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.logfactory`

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Please show the relevant code on your implementation.

Comment: Looks like you are asking the same question again. It's better described in your previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608460/javaagent-in-lotus-notes-6-5-using-axis-api-gives-exception-no-implementation-d

Comment: I was able to do this on one of the servers, BUT on another server it is not working at all. I tried almost everything.

Comment: Are you still using R6? If so I agree with @PanuHaaramo

Comment: Looks like i found the solution.. ATLAST all that was needed was a server restart. That did the trick..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i found the solution.. ATLAST all that was needed was a server restart. That did the trick..