# No implementation defined for LogFactory while using axis webservices in Lotus java agent

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, lotus-notes, agent

Hello Domino programmers!

As stated in title I decided to handle webservices on my own, using axis, compile it in Eclipse environment and finally use it in lotus java agent.

While my code exported to jar and ran outside Eclipse with success, after import to lotus notes agent I receive following error:

```
org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

I tried to apply answers from:

[JavaAgent in Lotus Notes 6.5 using axis api gives Exception "No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608460/javaagent-in-lotus-notes-6-5-using-axis-api-gives-exception-no-implementation-d)

But my tests ended only with more errors - setting system property ended with

```
User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4Logger' cannot be found or is not useable.
```

So, is there any workaround? I would like to call a webservice from Java agents, both local and on server.

Any help will be appreciated!

I work on 9.0 Server/Client