# No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: wildfly

We are trying to migrate from JBoss4.2.3 to Wildfly and When we are trying to deploy the war from JBoss4.2.3 to Wildfly11 we are getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.find(DiscoverClass.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)

        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
        ... 28 more
```

**Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.ca.pamsc.httpclient">
   <resources>
      <resource-root path="commons-httpclient-3.1.jar" />
   </resources>
   <dependencies>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
   </dependencies>
</module>
```

**War structure:**

```
acem.war
└───WEB-INF
    │   faces-config.xml
    │   filebrowse.tld
    │   jboss-deployment-structure.xml
    │   jboss-web.xml
    │   jsftaglib.tld
    │   userbrowse.tld
    │   web.xml
    │
    └───lib
            acem.jar
            axis.jar
            commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
            commons-digester-1.6.jar
            commons-discovery-0.2.jar
            commons-el-1.0.jar
            commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
            commons-io-1.3.1.jar
            commons-lang-2.6.jar
            cpchart.jar
            jaxb-api.jar
            jaxb-impl.jar
            jaxb1-impl.jar
            jsr173_1.0_api.jar
            jstl.jar
            myfaces-api.jar
            myfaces-impl.jar
            namespace.jar
            openviz2.jar
            relaxngDatatype.jar
            standard.jar
            tomahawk-1.1.5.jar
            wcom.jar
            xsdlib.jar
```

**Update 1:**
I have tried adding the Apache commons logging jar file manually to the modules folder but in this case it is giving the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl does not implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.verifyAncestory(ClassUtils.java:180)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.verifyAncestory(SPInterface.java:201)
```

**Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.ca.pamsc.httpclient">
<resources>
   <resource-root path="commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
</resources>
</module>
```

**Update2:**
Created the common-logging.properties file by referring to the below thread but still getting this error

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl does not implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

[JavaAgent in Lotus Notes 6.5 using axis api gives Exception "No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608460/javaagent-in-lotus-notes-6-5-using-axis-api-gives-exception-no-implementation-d)

Answer (score 0):

This was a "bug" in [`commons-logging-jboss-logmanager`](https://github.com/jboss-logging/commons-logging-jboss-logmanager/) project that was fixed in [1.0.3.Final](https://github.com/jboss-logging/commons-logging-jboss-logmanager/commit/67da91ab191a901ad12194e8cd16a555ad3311a2). The problem is some projects seem to repackage `commons-logging` and add a `META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` file which the default `commons-logging:commons-logging` JAR does not seem to have.

It should be safe to download [`org.jboss.logmanager:commons-logging-jboss-logmanager:1.0.3.Final`](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jboss/logmanager/commons-logging-jboss-logmanager/1.0.3.Final/commons-logging-jboss-logmanager-1.0.3.Final.jar) and replace the module. You'd just need to put the downloaded library in `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/commons/logging/main/` and edit the `module.xml` to point to the new version.